# Как обновить QLabel?

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
    def setTheme(self):
    backgroundImage = config.get("Theme","background")
    background = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
    background.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(252, 424))
    background.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(252, 424))
    if backgroundImage == 'default':
        background.setStyleSheet("image: url(data/images/background.png);")
    elif backgroundImage == 'dark':
        background.setStyleSheet("image: url(data/images/background2.png);")
    background.show()
```

Собственно. В другом классе я меняю значение background и снова вызываю метод setTheme. Однако изображение не меняется, хотя backgroundImage уже с нужным значением.

[ссылка на пример](https://dropmefiles.com/QRk6b)

Comment: мне кажется фон нужно менять не у лейбла, а у виджета под ним - у фрейма или окна

Comment: У меня там всё прозрачное, кроме лейбла и нужных окон. Для этого я фон через лейбл и делаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тут вы создаете новый QLabel при установки темы.

Уложите его в атрибут класса там где вы его создаете в первый раз, а потом

```
self.background_label.setStyleSheet(...)
self.background_label.update()
```

С внешнего класса лучше сделать signal-slot
на классе c backgroundLabel

```
class Window1(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def setTheme(self, backgroundImage):
        self.backgroundLabel.setStyleSheet(...)
        self.backgroundLabel.update()
```

на классе с настройками

```
class Window2(QObject):
    on_theme_changed = pyqtSignal(str)
    def onChanged(self):
        # ... обработать сеттингс тут чтоб не таскать в другие классы
        self.on_theme_changed.emit(backgroundImage)
```

Инит

```
w1 = Window1()
w2 = Window2()
w2.on_theme_changed.connect(w1.setTheme)
```

Comment: То есть, нужно создать его один раз в главном классе и потом просто менять StyleSheet? Сделал, ноль реакции.

Comment: @type49 попробуй добавить update() или repaint()

Comment: хотя setUpdatesEnabled(true); по умолчанию... У вас нет блока на функции которая setTheme вызывает?

Comment: Насчёт блока немного не понял. setTheme у меня вызывается в __init__ главного окна, а кнопка, в которой я меняю значения и снова её вызываю находится в другом окне другого класса. Но вызывается она нормально, если принтануть в ней backgroundImage, то после нажатия кнопки она выведет уже измененное значение.

Comment: попробуй update. возможно не тригернулось потому что вызванно из другого класса. надо сигнал-слотом классы соединять...

Comment: update в setTheme? тоже безрезультатно, как и repaint.

Comment: Сделай через сигнал тогда. Проблема похоже в том что классы не синзронизируются

Comment: Инструкция выше дала: TypeError: decorated slot has no signature compatible with SettingsWin.on_theme_changed[]

Comment: поправил, тип забыл указать

Comment: работает, огромное спасибо!

Comment: @type49 поставь галочку слева ответа если проблема решена

Answer (score 2):

Я увидел вашу задачу так:

**main.py**

```
import os
import configparser
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("Votre territoire")

        listCom = self.getComINSEE()
        self.cbCommunes = QComboBox()
        self.cbCommunes.addItems(listCom)
        self.cbCommunes.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionChange)

        self.backgroundLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.backgroundLabel.setFixedSize(QSize(252, 424))

        centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.cbCommunes)
        layout.addWidget(self.backgroundLabel)

        self.themeBackground = 'default'
        if os.path.exists('settingTheme.ini'):
            config = configparser.ConfigParser()
            config.read("settingTheme.ini")
            self.themeBackground   = config.get('Theme', 'background')

        if self.themeBackground == 'default':
            self.backgroundLabel.setStyleSheet("image: url(lena-2.png);")
        elif backgroundImage == 'dark':
            self.backgroundLabel.setStyleSheet("image: url(lena.jpg);")

    def getComINSEE(self):
        com = ['default', 'dark',]
        return com

    def selectionChange(self, i):
        text = self.cbCommunes.currentText()
        if text == 'default':
            self.backgroundLabel.setStyleSheet("image: url(lena-2.png);")
        elif text == 'dark':
            self.backgroundLabel.setStyleSheet("image: url(lena.jpg);")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**settingTheme.ini**

```
[Theme]
background = default
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://pastebin.com/iTz8CSBR у меня это реализовано вот так.

Comment: @type49 если вам действительно нужна помощь и вы хотите получать быстрые и правильные ответы - вы должны публиковать `минимально-ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫЙ` пример, который демонстрирует вашу проблему !!!

Comment: А как быть если программе доп модули нужны для минимальной воспроизводимости? Закидывать их на pastebin отдельно или прикреплять как то?

Comment: @@type49 `ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫЙ` - это когда копируется ваш пример и он запускается и показывает проблему. Вам надо опубликовать в вопросе ВСЕ модули, которые нужны для воспроизведения проблемы.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на минимальный пример в вопрос.

Comment: @type49 не надо ссылку ! Опубликуйте пример в теле вопроса !